# Calling a method in a smart contract: nonce has already been used, Nonce too low

Tags: ethereum, ethers.js, nonce, ether

I have a contract that has a simple method:

```
function getOwner() external returns (address) {
  return owner;
}
```

I'm trying to call it in `NodeJs` using `ethers` library:

```
// create the provider and the signer
const provider = new ethers.getDefaultProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545/");
let signer =  new ethers.Wallet('[privatekey]',
    provider );
let manager = new NonceManager(signer);

// create contract
let contractAddress = "[contractaddress]";
let abiString = fs.readFileSync(contractAbiPath).toString();
let abi = JSON.parse(abiString);
let contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
await contract.waitForDeployment();

// get the current nonce
let walletNonce = await signer.getNonce(); 

// send the transaction

// error1: if I pass walletNonce + 1
let transaction = await contract.getOwner({
    nonce: walletNonce
});
// error2 : if in the line above I passed walletNonce
let response = await manager.sendTransaction(transaction);
await response.wait(1);
```

If `walletNonce` is `6`, and I pass it like this: `nonce: walletNonce`, I get the error at line `let response = await manager.sendTransaction(transaction);`:

```
Nonce too low. Expected nonce to be 7 but got 6.'
```

However if I pass `nonce: walletNonce + 1`, I get the error at line

```
let transaction = await contract.getOwnerAddress({
    nonce: walletNonce
});
```

```
Nonce too high. Expected nonce to be 6 but got 7. Note that transactions can't be queued when automining.

could not coalesce error
```

I'm lost as to what to do.

Comment: can you re migrate and try it again

Answer (score 0):

either re migrate the project or from [nonce-too-high-error-with-metamask-and-hardhat](https://medium.com/@thelasthash/solved-nonce-too-high-error-with-metamask-and-hardhat-adc66f092cd)

> Open up your MetaMask window and click on the icon in the top right to
> display accounts. Go to Settings, then Advanced and hit Reset Account.
>
> Now the error will not appear when you make transactions.